# How do I set an ImageView in javaFX to have a url of an image on the internet?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I have a list of "Product" items that I fetch to show on my JavaFX screen, which contains a list of Images, Labels, and so on to represent the products. The product class contains a String URL which is basically the link to an image on the web.

I found that it works fine in SceneBuilder, as I can enter the image URL in the "Image" property, like this, and it shows up:

[image]

In my code, when I want to change this URL, I'm doing this:

```java
for(i=0;i<products.size();i++) {
    productsToDisplay.add(products.get(i));
    productImages.get(i).imageProperty().set(new Image(products.get(i).getImageURL())); 
}
```

But the image doesn't show up. Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Watch your code formatting. I fixed your today by wrapping in a pair of triple back-ticks.

Comment: What *exactly* is returned by `products.get(i).getImageURL()`? Put that return value in a declared local variable to prove its type.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

## `new Image( …URL…`

Just pass your URL as a string to the constructor.

To quote [the Javadoc](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/Image.html):

```
Image image3 = new Image("http://sample.com/res/flower.png", 100, 0, false, false);
```

### Example code

I cobbled together a crude little demo.

We define a list of a few URLs, as `String` objects. For each URL string, we instantiate an `ImageView` object. To each we give an `Image` object where the image came from over the internet via the URL string passed to its constructor.

[image: screenshot of example app with 3 ImageView objects, each assigned an Image object where the image file was obtained via a string URL over the internets]

```java
package work.basil.example.imagesex;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene ( this.makeImagesPane ( ) , 800 , 300 );
        stage.setTitle ( "Example of images from the Web" );
        stage.setScene ( scene );
        stage.show ( );
    }

    public FlowPane makeImagesPane ( )
    {
        FlowPane flow = new FlowPane ( );
        flow.setPadding ( new Insets ( 5 , 0 , 5 , 0 ) );
        flow.setVgap ( 4 );
        flow.setHgap ( 4 );

        List < String > urls =
                List.of (
                        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8f/Wikimedia_Hackathon_Prague_2019_-_Group_Photo_-_CLK_-_cropped.jpg/320px-Wikimedia_Hackathon_Prague_2019_-_Group_Photo_-_CLK_-_cropped.jpg" ,
                        // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wikimedia_Hackathon_Prague_2019_-_Group_Photo_-_CLK_-_cropped.jpg
                        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bb/Apollo_10_Lunar_Module.jpg" ,
                        // https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Apollo_10_Lunar_Module.jpg
                        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/72/Kumquat_from_Spain.jpg/320px-Kumquat_from_Spain.jpg"
                        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Kumquat_from_Spain.jpg
                );
        for ( String url : urls )
        {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView ( );
            imageView.setFitHeight ( 250 );
            imageView.setFitWidth ( 250 );
            imageView.setImage ( new Image ( url ) );
            flow.getChildren ( ).add ( imageView );
        }

        return flow;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch ( );
    }
}
```